# Preprocessor Statement to ask

Tags: c

I've write something like below:

```
#define ABC20
//#define   ABC10
//#define   ABC00

#ifdef ABC20
    #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC2"
#elif ABC10
    #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC1"
#elif ABC00
    #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC0"
#else
    #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "UNKNOWN"
#endif
```

And it can work.

But if I change to below:

```
//#define ABC20
#define   ABC10
//#define   ABC00

#ifdef ABC20
    #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC2"
#elif ABC10
    #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC1"
#elif ABC00
    #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC0"
#else
    #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "UNKNOWN"
#endif
```

When I compiled, it got error saying ABC10 is not declared. Do you guys know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use defined test:

```
#ifdef ABC20
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC2"
#elif defined ABC10
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC1"
#elif defined ABC00
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC0"
#else
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "UNKNOWN"
#endif
```

otherwise there is no condition for elif to check because after pre-processing you are left with:

```
#ifdef 
   #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC2"
#elif 
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC1"
#elif 
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC0"
#else
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "UNKNOWN"
#endif
```

but putting in the `defined` replaces the test with the result so you get:

```
#if   0
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC2"
#elif 1
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC1"
#elif 0
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC0"
#else
  #define  SYSTEMNAME                       "UNKNOWN"
#endif
```

Alternatively, you can define on flags with a `true` value, and rest of the flags with a false value without changing the tests:

```
#define ABC20 0
#define ABC10 1
#define ABC00 0
```

Comment: Could you explain more @perreal? I cannot understand. Tq.

Comment: it is like saying `else if ()` in C. You need a condition to check. You can also define ABC10 as 1 to make it work

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the same answer as already given, but I try to explain it from a different angel.

The directive `#elif` is the "else if" variant of `#if`. This directive takes an expression and checks if the value is true (i.e. non-zero). In this case, any variable used in the expression ought to exist. (Admittedly, the C standard says that any undefined symbols should be treated as though they exist with a value of 0 -- however, it is considered very bad practice to rely on this.)

In your case you are looking for the "else if" variant that corresponds to "#ifdef". This is written as follows:

```
#ifdef ABC20
#define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC2"
#elif defined(ABC10)
#define  SYSTEMNAME                       "ABC1"
...
```

The parenthesis after `defined` are optional, but makes the code much easier to read when included.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you define values... with nothing...  you only create the definition of them.
Therefore the first

```
    #ifdef ABC20
```

works...  as ABC20 is defined.

However when you comment out that line and ABC20 is no longer defined, you reach the

```
    #elif
```

This statement doesn't evaluate whether or not the value is defined, but looking test the definition itself ... which doesn't exist.

Try this instead

```
    //#define ABC20 1
    #define   ABC10 1
    //#define   ABC00 1
```